# Guide C++ Function Template Type

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I have the following, it accepts a function pointer type, and returns the typeid of each argument in a vector.

```
template <typename Ret, typename... Types>
auto ArgTypes(Ret(*pFn)(Types...))
{
    std::vector<std::type_index> vec;
    vec.insert(vec.end(), {typeid(Types)...});
    return vec;
}
```

I invoke it like this:

```
typedef int (*tExampleFn) (int a,bool b,char* c,long long d);
tExampleFn fakePtr = (tExampleFn)0;
auto argTypes = ArgTypes(&fakePtr);
```

As you can see, I have to make this fake function pointer for the template to work. I would instead like it to work like this:

```
template <typename Ret, typename... Types> // guide Ret and Types into shape Ret(*pFn)(Types...) somehow
auto ArgTypes()
{
    std::vector<std::type_index> vec;
    vec.insert(vec.end(), {typeid(Types)...});
    return vec;
}

typedef int (*tExampleFn) (int a,bool b,char* c,long long d);
auto argTypes = ArgTypes<tExampleFn>();
```

I cannot get the template to work this way. The first template arg Ret gets assinged the full type of the typedef tExampleFn. How can I guide the template to use the shape Ret(*pFn)(Types...), but *without* having to pass an intermediate function pointer.

Comment: Can you explain the real problem you're trying to solve? No, not the one about improving the usage of a function that returns a vector of type indexes. I'm referring to the problem to which you concluded the solution is a template function that returns a vector of type indexes, so that's what you're asking about. This is almost a certain rabbit hole, and I'll be surprised if there isn't a more proper, type-safe, natural C++ answer to whatever the real question is.

Comment: FWIW You could all you call the function from the first example like `ArgTypes(tExampleFn{})`

Comment: You need partial template specialization. Since it doesn't work for functions, make a template struct with a member function.

Comment: Unrelated: Your `ArgTypes` function could be simplified: `std::vector<std::type_index> ArgTypes(Ret(*pFn)(Types...)) { return {typeid(Types)...}; }`

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I am tracing an external system. This systems has functions with args, and I have logging code that needs to switch on the types of the args to do complex logic. I have typedefs for each external function. I am going to loop and then switch on the type hash code of each parameter. I want to specifically use the template just so that I can automatically convert these types to switchable numeric codes.

Comment: This is just generic, high level description that reveals nothing about the underlying C++ structures, so I can only give a generic answer: define a std::tuple to capture the parameter types, and some textbook-type template metaprogramming to handle the "switch on the type" part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone, I've combined the answers and comments with some external help into the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <typeindex>
#include <span>

typedef int (*tExampleFn) (int a,bool b,char* c,long long d);

template<typename T>
struct arg_types {};

template<typename R, typename... A>
struct arg_types<R(*)(A...)> {
    inline static const std::type_index value[] = {typeid(A)...};
};

template<typename T>
static constexpr std::span<const std::type_index> arg_types_v = arg_types<T>::value;

int main()
{
    auto vec = arg_types_v<tExampleFn>;
    for (const auto& t : vec)
    {
        std::cout << t.hash_code() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by NathanOliver you can call the first version via `ArgTypes(tExampleFn{})`.

To avoid creating an instance of the function pointer type altogether you can use partial template specialization. This doesn't work for function templates though.

```
#include <vector>
#include <typeindex>
#include <tuple>

template <typename Ret, typename... Types>
auto ArgTypes(Ret(*pFn)(Types...))
{
    std::vector<std::type_index> vec;
    vec.insert(vec.end(), {typeid(Types)...});
    return vec;
}

template <typename T>
struct arg_types;

template <typename Ret,typename ... Types>
struct arg_types<Ret(*)(Types...)> {
    auto operator()() {
        std::vector<std::type_index> vec;
        vec.insert(vec.end(), {typeid(Types)...});
        return vec;
    }
};

int main()
{
    typedef int (*tExampleFn) (int a,bool b,char* c,long long d);
    ArgTypes(tExampleFn{});
    arg_types<tExampleFn>{}();
}
```